# How to open a MDI child form using a MenuList on the main MDI parent form

Tags: vb.net

I have a MDI Parent form created with a MenuList, I also have the MDI child form created... how do I go about using the MenuList to open the MDI child form within the parent form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up added within the event this code:

```
    'Create a new instance of Form2
    Dim NewMDIChild As New frmProductMaintenance()
    'Set the parent of the MDI child form.
    NewMDIChild.MdiParent = Me
    'Display the new form.
    NewMDIChild.Show()
```